# MacOS DNS configuration: What is the difference between DomainName and SearchDomains

Tags: networking, macos, dns

`SearchDomains` are used to automatically post fix strings entered into tools like browsers. So, for example, if I add a search domain `mycompany.com` and then type `intranet` in the browser then the browser will try to resolve `intranet.mycompany.com`.

Search domains can be set from `System Preferences->Network->Advanced->DNS`. They can then be inspected using `scutil` with commands like

```
show State:/Network/Global/DNS
show Setup:/Network/Service/E594F5A4-6F0C-4505-B8CB-A62094A444F2/DNS
```

`SearchDomains` can also be set via `scutil` using something like:

```
d.init
d.add ServerAddresses "8.8.8.8"
d.add SearchDomains   ""
set Setup:/Network/Service/E594F5A4-6F0C-4505-B8CB-A62094A444F2/DNS
```

My question is, what is the `DomainName` key used for under DNS settings?

MacOS clearly recognises this. It's impossible (I believe) to view or set via the `System Preferences` UI. It can however be set via scutil by adding (for example) the line

```
d.add DomainName wibble.com
```

to the above snippet.

You can clearly see MacOS recognises it by viewing DNS with scutil

```
show State:/Network/Global/DNS
```

Any ideas?